# How to output a subtotal after the last instance of an element of an array

Tags: php, mysql, arrays

I am creating a report from a MySQL database that will show the time spent on clients of an accounting business.  I have an array called $test that holds the info for the report.  This array is already sorted in alphabetical order on [sort].

I use foreach to echo this array to an html table.  How can I output a subtotal after every client.  As you can see from the sample of $test below there are multiple instances of the client named JOHN Q ABERNATHY.  I need to echo a subtotal after the third JOHN Q ABERNATHY in this example.

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [sort] => ABERNATHY, JOHN Q
            [date] => 07-23-2015
            [client] => JOHN Q ABERNATHY
            [description] => test
            [user_name] => Jason
            [time_spent] => 00:10
            [amount] => 12.50
            [end] => 0
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [sort] => ABERNATHY, JOHN Q
            [date] => 07-23-2015
            [client] => JOHN Q ABERNATHY
            [description] => changed again
            [user_name] => Jason
            [time_spent] => 03:14
            [amount] => 242.50
            [end] => 0
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [sort] => ABERNATHY, JOHN Q
            [date] => 07-23-2015
            [client] => JOHN Q ABERNATHY
            [description] => time test again
            [user_name] => Jason
            [time_spent] => 00:53
            [amount] => 66.25
            [end] => 0
        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [sort] => BAUMAN, TERRY L
            [date] => 07-23-2015
            [client] => TERRY L BAUMAN
            [description] => test ind
            [user_name] => Jerry
            [time_spent] => 00:00
            [amount] => 0.00
            [end] => 0
        )

    [4] => Array
        (
            [sort] => Bethany Baptist
            [date] => 07-01-2015
            [client] => Bethany Baptist
            [description] => lots of work
            [user_name] => Jason
            [time_spent] => 05:25
            [amount] => 406.25
            [end] => 0
        )

    [5] => Array
        (
            [sort] => Johnson Mortuary Service, LLC
            [date] => 07-31-2015
            [client] => Johnson Mortuary Service, LLC
            [description] => pr
            [user_name] => Jason
            [time_spent] => 00:04
            [amount] => 5.00
            [end] => 0
        )

    [6] => Array
        (
            [sort] => COLEMAN, MIKE R
            [date] => 07-31-2015
            [client] => MIKE R COLEMAN
            [description] => PHONE CONCERNING PAYMENT PLAN
            [user_name] => Jason
            [time_spent] => 00:20
            [amount] => 25.00
            [end] => 0
        )
```

My subtotals are stored in an array called $sum. Here is a section of my code where I store the subtotals to $sum and echo $test out to a table:

```
    $sum = array();
    $end = array();
    foreach($test as $key => $value) {

        //The following code puts subtotals of the $test array into a new array called $sum
        if (!isset($sum[$value['sort']])) {
            $sum[$value['sort']] = 0;
        }
        $sum[$value['sort']] += $value['amount'];
        //end of summing code

        //This is where I am trying to create the subtotal but obviously have not gotten very far

        if (!isset($end[$value['sort']])) {
            $end[$value['sort']] = 0;
            prev($test);

            $end[$value['sort']] = 1;

            next($test);
        }


        $date2=$value['date'];
        $client2=$value['client'];
        $description2=$value['description'];
        $user_name2=$value['user_name'];
        $time_spent2=$value['time_spent'];
        $amount2=$value['amount'];

        echo 
        "
            <tr>
                <td>$date2</td>
                <td>$client2</td>
                <td>$description2</td>
                <td>$user_name2</td>
                <td>$time_spent2</td>
                <td class='text-right'>$$amount2</td>
            </tr>
        ";  
    }
```

How can I tell when the foreach has looped through the last instance of JOHN Q ABERNATHY so that I can echo his total [amount]?

Comment: I edited my answer below, please be sure you have the latest changes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
  $sum = 0;
    $first = true;
    echo "<Table border='1'>";
    foreach($test as $key => $value) {

        if(!$first && $oldClient !== $value['client'])
        {
            //Sub-total info goes here.
            echo
            "
                <tr>
                    <td colspan='6'>$oldClient $sum</td>
                </tr>
            ";

            //Reset the sum variable
            $sum = 0;
        }

        $oldClient = $value['client'];

        $sum += $value['amount'];

        $date2=$value['date'];
        $client2=$value['client'];
        $description2=$value['description'];
        $user_name2=$value['user_name'];
        $time_spent2=$value['time_spent'];
        $amount2=$value['amount'];

        echo
        "
                <tr>
                    <td>$date2</td>
                    <td>$client2</td>
                    <td>$description2</td>
                    <td>$user_name2</td>
                    <td>$time_spent2</td>
                    <td class='text-right'>$$amount2</td>
                </tr>
            ";
        $first = false;
    }

    //Sub-total info goes here as well to handle the last group.    
    echo
    "
                <tr>
                    <td colspan='6'>$oldClient $sum</td>
                </tr>
            ";

    echo '</table>';
```

On each loop the following occurs:

- client name is set to a temp variable
- The temp client variable $oldCLient is compared to $value['client']. If they do not match and it is not the first loop that means a group of identical client has passed and it time to print the subtotal.

Take note that you will also have to

- print the subtotal for the last client group after the for each loop
- That I've changed the sum from an array to an int. It gets reset to 0 after each client group's subtotal is printed to screen
- I've also removed the 'end' array. It is not needed.